# Escaping $$ in `replace` function

Tags: javascript

I met next trouble on my way:

```
"abc".replace("ab","$$ $$")
>>> "$ $c"
"abc".replace("ab","\$\$ \$\$")
>>> "$ $c"
```

How i can escape `$` symbol ?

Comment: What do you want the output to be?

Comment: @p.s.w.g: I'm assuming "$$ $$c".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the replacement string, `$$` = `$`. So if you really want `$$`, use `$$$$`.

```
"abc".replace("ab","$$$$ $$$$") // "$$ $$c"
```

No backslashes are required. [Details in the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.11).

---

Side note: Only the *first* occurrence of `ab` will be replaced, because your first argument is a string. E.g.:

```
"abc abc abc".replace("ab","$$$$ $$$$") // "$$ $$c abc abc"
```

If you wanted *all* occurrences replaced, you'd have to make your first argument a regular expression with the `g` (global) flag:

```
"abc abc abc".replace(/ab/g,"$$$$ $$$$") // "$$ $$c $$ $$c $$ $$c"
```

Comment: I actually tried my wrong answer and saw the result, but my brain just took the backslashes out :)

Comment: Here's the docs to back this up: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter